Reading Data Using Modbus RTU Over RS-485
I would like to receive data from E95-DTU-433L20-485 via Modbus RTU. I could not read data properly. Could you help me figure out what the problem with my configuration is?
#include "LoRa_E32.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int8_t temperature;  

SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2);
LoRa_E32 e32(&mySerial);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  e32.begin();
}

void loop() {
  
  temperature = 22; 

  Serial.println(temperature, BIN);  
  
  struct Message {
    int8_t temperature;  
  } message;

  message.temperature = temperature;  

  ResponseStatus rs = e32.sendFixedMessage(0, 63, 23, &message, sizeof(Message));
  Serial.println(rs.getResponseDescription());
  delay(1000); 
}



We don't know how you have connected it and if you are using correct parameters for the device. Have you got a manual how to connect it and how to communicate with it?

It could be a hardware issue too. Please, provide the schematic of your setup.

You seem to be using Arduino libraries for the modem and software serial. Also there seems to be no control for RS-485 transmit enable. Like I said, we don't know how you have connected this in hardware and will it ever work. For the software, this is a pure Arduino library usage question. For the electronics part, it's "how do I use my electrical device" if it's not about how to interface with it in hardware.

I am using SH-U10 usb to RS-485 converter I connected A to A, B to B for both devices. I don't know what the problem is coming from hardware or software.I have only user manuel document. (https://www.cdebyte.com/products/E95-DTU(433L20-485)-V8/4#Downloads)

@Mehmet So there's many potential problems already. RS-485 is not a two-wire interface. It is a three-wire interface with common ground reference and two data wires between devices. You mention no termination either. And you can never be sure if devices label A and B correctly, but you can try swapping or use oscilloscope to be sure.
